# Could not find method commandLine()

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm attempting to add a pre-pre-build shell script to my gradle/Android-Studio build. I've added the following to `app/build.gradle`:

```groovy
task prePreBuild << {
  commandLine 'ls'
}
preBuild.dependsOn prePreBuild
```

When I invoke my build with `./gradlew assembleDebug` I get the following error:

```
Could not find method commandLine() for arguments [ls] on project ':app'
```

If I replace the `commandLine` line with something like `println 'Hello'` then it works fine, and I can see the output from my new task.

I searched for other mentions of "Could not find method commandLine" and found nothing. What is the correct way to invoke a shell script from this gradle task?

Comment: which version of gradle are you using?

Comment: @Blackbelt `./gradlew -v` says Gradle 2.4

Comment: @Blackbelt I get pretty much the same error with that change: "> Could not find method executable() for arguments [ls] on project ':app'."

Comment: newhouse is right. Task has to be of type Exec

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to indicate the type of the task or use the `exec` block:

```
task execute(type: Exec) {

}
```

or

```
exec {

}
```

You can find more info on https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html

Comment: Thanks! Changing the first line of my example to `task prePreBuild(type:Exec) {` fixed the problem.