# How to use commandLine() within buildFinished

Tags: gradle

In `$HOME/.gradle/init.gradle` I have:

```
gradle.buildFinished { buildResult ->
    commandLine 'bash', "blah blah blah"
}
```

Doing `gradle build` the build succeeds, but after it succeeds I get the error:

> Could not find method commandLine() for arguments [bash, blah blah blah] on build 'FooBar' of type org.gradle.invocation.DefaultGradle.

The answer to the question [Could not find method commandLine()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36185602/1020588) doesn't help as either putting `(type: Exec)` after `gradle.buildFinished` or wrapping the whole thing in `exec { }` causes Gradle to fail right from the start rather than the build succeeding and then my post-build hook failing.

I'm using Gradle version 6.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've misconfigured `commandLine`. With the following `build.gradle`:

```
task lol {
    doLast {
        println "lol"
    }
}
```

and `~/.gradle/init.gradle`:

```
gradle.buildFinished { buildResult ->
    exec { 
        commandLine 'bash', '-c', 'echo lol2'
    }
}
```

it works as expected.